# Get filename from route

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have route like `/gcp/filename`

```
import downloadGCP from './controllers/downloadGCP';
router.route('/gcp')
    .get(downloadGCP);
```

inside `./controllers/downloadGCP.js`, how should I get the `filename`? Below is code for  `downloadGCP.js`

```
export default async (req, res) => {
//<--To get filename
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The route `/gcp` will not match `GET /gcp/filename` request. I think the route should be `/gcp/:filename` (`filename` is a "variable" name).

Now, you can get `filename` value by `req.params.filename`.

Answer (score 0):

To get filename you need to first configure your router like this

```
import downloadGCP from './controllers/downloadGCP';
router.route('/gcp/:filename').get(downloadGCP);
```

and inside downloadGCP to get the file you need to get the file from request, like so:

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  const file = req.params.file 

  ...other stuff...
}
```

or depending on how you have structured and send your request

```
 export default async (req, res) => {
      const file = req.body.file // or req.file
    
      ...other stuff...
    }
```